# Filtering orders having one item and not having another one in the same time

Tags: mysql, sql

I have very simple one-to-many relation (tables Orders-Items) where one order can have zero or more items.

What's the best way (SQL query) to filter only orders having item1 (item_id=1) and no item2 (item_id=2) in the same time?

At the moment I use the following SQL query:

```
SELECT o.order_id
  FROM orders o
  JOIN items i ON i.order_id=o.order_id
 WHERE i.item_id=1
   AND o.order_id NOT IN (SELECT o2.order_id
                            FROM orders o2
                            JOIN items i2 ON i2.order_id=o2.order_id
                           WHERE i2.item_id=2)
```

Comment: Can you show us table data example, are you sure you will always have just itemID 1 and 2? Will you have more of those at some point?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I prefer to approach these types of questions using `group by` and `having`:

```
SELECT i.order_id
FROM items i
GROUP BY i.order_id
HAVING SUM(i.item_id = 1) > 0 AND
       SUM(i.item_id = 2) = 0;
```

Some notes:

- You don't need to join in `orders`, because you have `order_id` in `items`.
- Each condition in the having clause is counting the number of items.  The first says there is at least one of item 1 and the second that there is no item 2.
- I removed the `where` clause.  If you were to have one, then it would be `WHERE i.item_id IN (1, 2)`.

EDIT:

In any database other than MySQL, you would use this `HAVING` clause:

```
HAVING SUM(CASE WHEN i.item_id = 1 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) > 0 AND
       SUM(CASE WHEN i.item_id = 2 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) = 0;
```

This will work in MySQL as well; I just like the shorter notation.

Comment: Well noted and explained. However, this "trick" with summing of logical expressions SUM(i.item_id=1) is something new to me. Good one.

Answer (score 1):

No need for a correlated subquery, use the `HAVING` clause.

This excludes all `order_id`s where an item_id = 2 exists.

```
SELECT o.order_id
FROM orders o
JOIN items i ON i.order_id=o.order_id
WHERE i.item_id=1
GROUP BY o.order_id
HAVING SUM(item_id = 2) = 0;
```

Or you could do

```
SELECT o.order_id
FROM orders o
JOIN items i ON i.order_id=o.order_id
WHERE i.item_id=1
GROUP BY o.order_id
HAVING COUNT(DISTINCT item_id) = 1;
```

to make sure it has only `item_id = 1`. Several ways to do it, depending on what you want to do exactly.